# in python, how would I extract a section of an XML

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

Give the XML below

```
<soap:Envelope
        xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap:Body>
                <A>
                    <B>
                        <Id>55</Id>
                        <Name>My Name</Name>
                    </B>
                </A>
        </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How would I extract the entire "B" section?  i.e. How would I extract this section:

```
    <B>
        <Id>55</Id>
        <Name>My Name</Name>
    </B>
```

I tried using [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).But, I can't get it work.  What I've tried are:

```
root = ET.fromstring(data)
r = root[0][0][0]
```

But that only gave me the tag itself:

```
<Element 'B' at 0x10b7aa590>
```

Comment: `print(ET.tostring(r))` will show that `r` contains everything you want.

Comment: Thanks @JustinEzequiel , So would `r = root[0][0][0]` be the correct way to retrieve that "B" section? or can I key off of the name of the B element?

Comment: Not sure what you want but you can try: `for b in root.iterfind('.//B'): print(ET.tostring(b))`

Comment: @JustinEzequiel You can convert your first comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(ET.tostring(r))
```

will show that `r` contains everything you want.

to get at the **B** elements directly you can try

```
for b in root.iterfind('.//B'):
    print(ET.tostring(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
from lxml import etree

bee = """your xml above"""    
doc = etree.fromstring(bee)
target = doc.xpath('//B')
print(etree.tostring(target[0]).decode())
```